# Не работает markerclusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: this_url+'&view=json',
    success: function(data){
        for (var key in data.markers){
            markers[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: parseFloat(data.markers[key].lat), lng: parseFloat(data.markers[key].lon)},
                title: data.markers[key].name
            });
        }
    }
});

markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: 13,
    gridSize: 50,
    styles: null
});
```

в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было просто сделать так:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: this_url+'&view=json',
    success: function(data){
        for (var key in data.markers){
            markers[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: parseFloat(data.markers[key].lat), lng: parseFloat(data.markers[key].lon)},
                title: data.markers[key].name
            });
        }
        markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            maxZoom: 13,
            gridSize: 25,
            styles: null,
            imagePath: '../includes/js-marker-clusterer/images/m'
        });
    }
});
```